# Reorder character column using a numeric column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that I want to reorder one of the columns based on another column which is numeric. I used the following code, which logically should work but it's not working as expected:

`s10_data <- df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(State = State %>% fct_reorder(colB,.desc = TRUE))`

Data

| State | Year | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anambra state | 2020 | 163422 | 106136 | 35 |
| Abia State | 2020 | 87267 | 89149 | -2 |
| Adamawa State | 2020 | 178604 | 104867 | 41 |
| Akwa-Ibom State | 2020 | 140756 | 141507 | -1 |
| Bauchi State | 2020 | 188425 | 141852 | 25 |
| Benue State | 2020 | 143272 | 146595 | -2 |
| Borno State | 2020 | 176018 | 139283 | 21 |
| Bayelsa State | 2020 | 22593 | 22496 | 0 |

Please help. I am confused.

Comment: 1. Don't add data as image. Add it in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) 2. What is your expected output? 3. Do you need `s10_data <- df1 %>% arrange(desc(colB))` ?

Comment: Resolved. It was not working because of package conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The problem was due to package conflicts with other packages that I was using in my script. Thank you. This was really funny but insightful

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you paste the output into your answer directly rather than using an image. Images have the tendency to go missing and that makes the answer less useful for others in the future. Also, feel free to accept your answer (green tick) if you feel like it's solved the problem.